# no member function declared in class 'MainWindow'

Tags: c++, qt

I'm trying to make a fake FBI program for a prank, but it's not as easy as I expected it to be.
This is my code.

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    ui->trackConnButton->setEnabled(false);
}

void MainWindow::on_confirmButton_clicked() {
    if (ui->usernameText == "name" && ui->passwordText == "password") {
        ui->resullabel->setText("Password accepted.");
        ui->trackConnButton->setEnabled(true);
    } else {
        ui->resullabel->setText("Password denied.");
    }
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}
```

I get this error:

```
D:\Qt-Projekte\test3\mainwindow.cpp:12: Fehler: no 'void MainWindow::on_confirmButton_clicked()' member function declared in class 'MainWindow'
 void MainWindow::on_confirmButton_clicked() {
                                           ^
```

My question is now: how to fix it?
Thanks in advance.

my mainwindow.h:

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>

namespace Ui {
class MainWindow;
}

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MainWindow();

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
};

#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

Comment: When asking about compilation errors: please copy-paste the error text, instead of paraphrasing it.

Comment: Show us the definition of the `MainWindow` class (presumably in `mainwindow.h`).  It looks like you forgot the function declaration for `on_confirmButton_clicked`.

Comment: @0x5453 done, I hope it's okay like that.

Comment: @1hund Their question answers your question already (did you read entire comment, or did you only read the first sentence?). There is no declaration of `on_confirmButton_clicked` in `MainWindow`.

Answer (score 0):

All member functions of a class must contain a "declaration" and a "definition".

For example:

```
struct Foo {
    // Declarations
    void foo() const;
    int bar(int x);
};

// Definitions
void Foo::foo() const {
    std::cout << "foo" << std::endl;
}
int Foo::bar(int x) {
    return x + 1;
}
```

(Note that if you define a function inline in a class, it counts as both definition and declaration):

```
struct Foo {
    // Declaration AND definition
    void foo() const {
        std::cout << "foo inline" << std::endl;
    }
};
```

So in your case, you must declare the `on_confirmButton_clicked` function inside the definition of class `MainWindow`.

Comment: I still don't fully understand it. Can you show it with my code, please?

Comment: Inside the `MainWindow` class, in the section marked `public`, add a line that says `void on_confirmButton_clicked();`.